Show that $ 2^n\sum_{N=1}^{[R]}\binom{N+n-1}{n-1}\le (\frac{CR}{n})^n $.
Recall that Stirling's formula states that for any integers $k\ge 1$, we have
$$
k!=(1+o(1))\sqrt{2\pi k}(\frac{k}{e})^k.
$$
I try to show that for integers $n\ge 1, N\ge 1$ and $R>n$, we have
$$
2^n\sum_{N=1}^{[R]}\binom{N+n-1}{n-1}\le (\frac{CR}{n})^n
$$
for some positive constant $C>0$ which is independent on $R$ or $n$.

I try to apply the Stirling's formula:
$$
\sum_{N=1}^{[R]}\binom{N+n-1}{n-1}=\sum_{N=1}^{[R]}\frac{(1+o(1))}{(1+o(1))^2\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sqrt{N+n-1}(N+n-1)^{N+n-1}}{\sqrt{N(n-1)}(n-1)^{n-1}N^N}
$$
I am stuck here... How to upper this summation?

$$\sum_{N=0}^r\binom{N+m}m=\binom{m+r+1}{m+1}$$ Letting $m=n-1,$ $r=[R],$ your sum is $\binom{[R]+n}{n}-1.$

This doesn't look right, because, as $n\to\infty,$ the right side goes to zero while the left side goes to $+\infty.$ And if $C$ is supposed to depend on $n,$ then why not just replace the whole right side with $DR^n$ for some  $D$ depending on $n.$

Is it maybe supposed to be $2^{-n}?$ That doesn't look right, either, but may be closer.

@ThomasAndrews Sorry, we need to add extra condition that is $R>n$.

Add it to the question. A person shouldn't have to read through all the commenta to know what your question means.

@ThomasAndrews Absolutely! I already added it in my question.

@Hermi Can I have your feedback on my answer?

We know that [1]:
$$\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^k \leq {n \choose k} \leq \left( \frac{en}{k}\right)^k$$
Hence, using the identity [2] also suggested by @ThomasAndrews in a comment, for $[R]>n$  we have
$$\sum_{N=1}^{[R]}\binom{N+n-1}{n-1}=\binom{[R]+n}{n}-1\le\binom{2[R]}{n} \le \\ \left(\frac{2e[R]}{n}\right)^n\le \left(\frac{2eR}{n}\right)^n,$$
which yields the result for $C=4e$ after multiplying both sides by $2^n$.
